# MySQL split comma separated values and GROUP BY result

Tags: php, mysql

I have table as bellow.

t1

```
+---------+-------------+ 
| id      | value       |  
+---------+-------------+ 
| 1       |  A,B,C,D    | 
| 2       |  B,C,E,F    | 
| 3       |  E,F,G,H    | 
| 4       |  G,A,E,N    | 
+---------+-------------+
```

I want a query split value and then group by result. like

```
+-------+ 
|result |  
+-------+ 
|  A    | 
|  B    | 
|  C    | 
|  D    | 
+-------+
```

I try following but it's fail.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', 1) as result
FROM t1 GROUP BY result
```

anyone to give better hint thanks

Comment: What do you mean by '_group by matched_'? `D` has no match anywhere yet it's included in your results

Comment: doesn't deserve to give minus one, anyway I mean group by return result value.

Comment: I didn't give it -1, I was just asking for clarity about what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you are looking to output.  I *think* you are saying that you want to return the values from the `value` column that occur *more than once* in any row in your comma-separated list.

In that case, the following query will produce the output you want:

```
SELECT  result
  FROM  (
        SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', a.letter + 1), ',', -1) result
          FROM  t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT 0 letter UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) a ON LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(value) - a.letter
        ) a
  GROUP BY result
  HAVING COUNT(result) > 1
  ORDER BY result
```

OUTPUT:

```
result
A
B
C
E
F
G
```

Why these results? Each of these letters occurs *at least twice* in the comma-separated lists.  For example, `A` occurs twice (in row 1 and row 4), `E` occurs three times (in rows 2, 3, and 4), etc.

Note: This currently supports comma-separated lists of **up to 4 letters only**.  It's not clear from your sample data whether this is enough or not.

**Edit following OP comment**

To get a list of all of the letters, change to use this SQL:

```
SELECT  result
  FROM  (
        SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, ',', a.letter + 1), ',', -1) result
          FROM  t1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT 0 letter UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) a ON LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(value) - a.letter
        ) a
  GROUP BY result
  ORDER BY result
```

Removing the `HAVING COUNT(result) > 1` will cause all results to be returned.

Comment: as you said if letters occurs twice above query returning correct result but now what to do with values not occur twice? I need them to be listed in same result :(

Comment: @ash So you just want all of the letters regardless of whether they occur once, twice, or more?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: @ash See the updated code

Comment: thank you that worked, I'm selecting this as accepted answer, but link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad changed my mind I want to use separated value only for reading will change design for insert and update.

Comment: @ash Thank you, and I think you've made the right choice.  I'm glad to have helped but changing your data structure is definitely the best way forward